# Graphics card isn't recognized and drivers can't be installed: "install package failure!"

Tags: windows-7, drivers, multiple-monitors, graphics-card

I just assembled my new PC. Everything seems to work fine for one detail: the onboard graphic chipset gets priority over my PCI-e card.

**Motherboard:** MSI Z87-GD65 Gaming
**GPU:** Sapphire Dual-X R9 270X 2GB GDDR5 OC Boost Lite
**OS:** Windows 7 64-bit
**PSU:** Corsair RM750

In the UEFI I go to `Settings > Advanced > Integrated Graphics Configuration`.
These are my settings:

```
Virtu Technology                   [Disabled]
Initiate Graphic Adapter           [PEG]
Integrated Graphics Share Memory   [64M]
DVMT Memory                        [256MB]
IGD Multi-Monitor                  [Enabled]
```

Still I don't get any visual on either of my 3 screens when I connect them with the graphics card. When I use the onboard VGA thingy, I get an image on that screen.

My screens are connected with DVI-To-VGA, DVI and HDMI.

In the device management settings I have disabled the "Standard-VGA graphical adapter", this didn't yield any result (in fact, it didn't do anything. I would have expected to have no image on the onboard card either, but I do).

In the same window I can also see that under "Other devices" there is an entry "Unknown device". Searching for a driver in the context menu doesn't find anything.

I have tried installing the drivers both by downloading them and using the install CD. During installation, I get the error "Application Install: install package failure!"

Using the AMD Driver Autodetect, I get the error message "We were unable to find your product or OS".

I looked at [this post](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1875663/amd-catalyst-drivers-installing-application-install-install-package-failure.html), but Driver Fusion doesn't find any graphic drivers for the Intel family.

Any suggestions?

Update:

I just connected the power supply with the graphics card (appearantly I forgot that before) and tried to boot the PC, but now I don't get any image at all. Not with the onboard one nor the PCI-e one.

When I disconnect the PCI-e card, I can use the onboard one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to update this.

I ordered a new video card the same evening and received it this morning: the moment I plugged the new one in it worked just fine. Drivers installed immediately as well.

Comment: So the card was bad? I can relate. Several years ago, I bought an AIW Rage from Computer Center, but just couldn’t get it to work; I had the same sort of errors you described. I figured out that the card in the box was a slightly different model and likely returned and resold, so I returned it. A few years later, my AIW 9000 stopped working and I got the same errors again. I contacted ATI and they said it was probably dead from heat or something. Fortunately I bought the extended warranty from Future Shop, so I was able to exchange it for an AIW 9600—the lowest AIW they had available—for free.